# Python Flask yield text files

Tags: python, flask

I have a simple flask app that runs some back end functions that grab retrieve data from a bunch of different places adds that data to text files. I'm then reading through all the text files and yielding them to the page. I'm doing it like this:

```
@app.route("/metrics", methods=["GET"])
def metrics():

def generate():

    Metrics.GetMetrics().metrics()

    settings = get_config()
    metrics_folder = settings['settings'].get('metrics_folder', '/opt/metrics/')

    all_metrics = []

    for filename in os.listdir(metrics_folder):
        if filename != '.gitignore':
            m = open(metrics_folder + filename)
            for l in m.readlines():
                all_metrics.append(l)

    for metric in all_metrics:
        yield metric

return Response(stream_with_context(generate()), mimetype='text/plain')
```

This works fine, but the number of files that I'm working with keeps increasing (up to 38k) and I've started to notice a slowdown. I was wondering if anyone smarter then me had any ideas or tips on how I could do this more efficiently? Maybe something with multiprocessing? Or maybe a way to cat out all the files in the directory and throw them all at the webpage at the same time instead of using the stream_with_context? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I agree with you if there is no way to to put everything in one database, and you truly need to examine multiple files and then compile it into one text document etc., I would look into asynchronous programming, other wise it is going to execute one command at a time and take a while: https://realpython.com/python-async-features/

In case you need the link to get started.

Comment: Thanks @NewCoder18, I'll take a look!

Comment: Also, now that I read database out loud, that might be the answer. I can just setup a DB and instead of string all the data in files, I'll just save it to the database. I would guess querying the database would be much quicker then reading thousands of files.

Comment: Yeah, that is why I said that first, if you CAN put it into a database do it, if you can't then the second option is fine.

Comment: Would it be better to pull the data from the database and do something similar to what I'm doing. Iterate trough each row in the database, yielding that row to the stream_with_context. Or would it be more efficient to pass the data into a template and iterate through the rows in the template?

Comment: Yes, database, 100%, and you can create multiple databases and then link the data, it is way more efficient than files and that is why you typically hear most companies do this and to try work with 'files' only when needed. Stack: (Input Data) Frontend Website > (Parse Data) Backend Flask > Database (Storage and Reuse)

Comment: So I've spun up a mysql database, but writing to that takes longer then writing to 38k files. I still think it's the answer to the question, but I'll need to figure out a more efficient way to bulk write 38k rows to a mysql table.

Comment: Here is where it may be a good idea to use a async programming, along with multiple databases, and try to optimize read and write. Figuring out how to manage large amounts of data and processing it efficiently is very dependent on each individual situation, but I am glad you are on the right path!